# Adaptive Payments - Delay Payment Until Seller Confirms

Tags: paypal

Background:

We are creating a marketplace where we connect consumers with producers.

Workflow:

1) Consumer uploads an object to be produced
2) We present a list of eligible producers
3) Consumer selects producer from list
4) Consumer pays
5) Producer notified of job, can ACCEPT/REJECT job
6a) If ACCEPT - producer creates product and delivers to consumer
6b) If REJECT - consumer issued refund

Problem:

How can we automate a refund if the producer rejects? Does paypal offer a confirmation system, or will this have to be implemented by an outside function? If Paypal has an "accept/reject" payment, then everything can be handled in the paypal environment. If Paypal DOES NOT have this functionality, we'll most likely have to have an automated email system that will require the producer to Accept/Reject in which we'll have to manually issue a refund.

Comment: That isn't real efficient at scale @Tianyun, which is why they used the term "automate" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IPN to get notified once a payment completes.  Then set up an interface that the producer clicks accept or deny.  If they click deny, you could have that system make a Refund API call to send the money back to the buyer.  This would allow you to automate the system.

Comment: Chad,

Thank you for your response. 

Is there a way to actually hold the funds from the consumer, request a confirmation from the producer, and then release the funds to the producer?

I figure this might be possible with a Delayed Chained process, but we'd need a trigger (confirmation) to initiate the release of funds. If the producer does not respond in 48 hours, the funds would have to automatically be refunded.

I am unsure if this is a possibility.

Comment: Correct, you could use a Delayed Chained payment for this.  I am not sure how your system is set up, but I would have all this information in a database, and then set your system up to run a cron job and check to see if a producer has not responded in 48hrs, and then execute the refund if they have not.

Comment: Chad,


Just a thought: In Immediate Chained Payments (not delayed), can the Primary Account issue a full refund to the customer? The refund would withdraw the original deposit from both accounts (primary, secondary) respectively.


In addition, could you make the producer responsible for the refund transaction fee?